# Why ag grid ignoring the defaultExcelExportParams option supplied?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, excel, ag-grid

Below is my React ag grid code. I am trying to pass the `processCellCallback` function, but I don't see the console.log coming to the browser console when I do export excel operation. Any idea what am I missing?

```
<StyledTableRoot
  className='ag-theme-alpine'
  style={{ height: 600, width: '98%' }}
>
  <AgGridReact
    gridOptions={GRID_OPTIONS}
    onGridReady={onGridReady}
    rowData={rowData}
    onFirstDataRendered={onFirstDataRendered}
    onFilterChanged={onFilterChanged}
    frameworkComponents={{
      actionsRenderer: ActionButtons,
      dateEditor: CustomDateEditor,
    }}
    rowSelection={'multiple'}
    suppressRowClickSelection={true}
    onSelectionChanged={onSelectionChanged}
    immutableData={true}
    getRowNodeId={(data) => data.id}
    pagination={true}
    defaultExcelExportParams={{
      autoConvertFormulas: true,
      processCellCallback: (params) => {
        console.log(params);
        const field = params.column.getColDef().field;
        return params.value;
      },
    }}
  ></AgGridReact>
</StyledTableRoot>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (but using plain javascript) and solved replacing ag-grid-enterprise.min.noStyle.js with [ag-grid-enterprise.min.js](https://unpkg.com/@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules@25.3.0/dist/ag-grid-enterprise.min.js)

Comment: I had to upgrade the lib. The version I had was not capable to support it.